# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1 Error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After switching to DNX and upgrading to Beta4 we get the following error only when publishing to a server.  The code runs locally in VS.  We made sure the server had KRE removed and DNX upgraded.  Any suggestions?

Error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[System.String]'.

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GetCurrentValues(ViewContext viewContext, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, String expression, Boolean allowMultiple)
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Criteria.Level, Enum.GetNames(typeof(LogManager.Web.Models.EventLevels)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Value = e }), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

project.json

```
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Distributed": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.NLog": "1.0.0-beta4"
```

DNX version is Beta4.

Comment: What version of the runtime (DNX) are you using and what packages do you have in `project.json`?

Comment: Hey Victor, I added more information above.  We are having this same issue with 2 completely different MVC 6 sites.  It seems like we are maybe missing something on the server?  We made sure we ran the dnvm upgrade on the server but that didnt fix it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/5605f63ddc832ef4d90cb53133eac823a6a531d0

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest DNX, the problem is fixed there (2015-08-24 it is Beta6).

```
dnvm upgrade
```

Also you need to change the project to use that latest dnx version by right clicking the project:
[image]

Then you need to change all of your **beta4 in project.json** to this version you installed (intellisense doesn't seem to help you correctly there, so ie. beta6 might be there even if it is not shown).

Some trics are needed in the startup.cs to make everything run correctly. check what doesn't compile and try to fix those compilation errors.